# Check if jQuery or mooTools are loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, mootools

In my project I am using `jQuery` in client side and `mooTools` in admin side.
I would like to be able to write some part of code (google maps functions, etc) which will be common for both of that libraries.

Is it possible to check if `jQuery` or `mooTools` libraries are loaded and use proper behaviours ?

`$(document).ready(function() {});` or `window.addEvent('domready', function(){});`

`$('#id');` or `$('id');`

`$('googleMapLocalize').addEvent('click', function(){});` or `$('googleMapLocalize').bind('click', function(){});`

What is the best way ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Both are adding global varibles with its names:

MooTools and jQuery

So just check:

```
if(window.MooTools) or if(window.jQuery)
```

Answer (score 8):

Simple:

```
if ($ === window.jQuery) alert('$ bound to jQuery');

if ($() === document.id()) alert('$ bound to MooTools');
```

Should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

We use **typeof** for this

```
if(typeof jQuery !== 'undefined')
```

or

```
if(typeof MooTools !== 'undefined')
```